# Gather list of all IDs ordered by submission date and ID by parsing file path

Tags: object-oriented, console, powershell

This code is to gather a sorted list of IDs (first by ID, then by date) recursively from a directory that submitted a particular type of file (that, as you can tell, includes the word "Magic") and then outputs the IDs paired with the modified date (the closest proxy I have for the submission date) to a CSV.  (Where I then dedupe by ID to get the earliest submission for each ID/find average number of unique IDs submitted a month over the year/ the total submitted for the year):

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *Magic* |  
Where-Object {$_.lastWriteTime -gt '01/01/2018' -AND $_.lastWriteTime -lt '12/31/2018'} | 
Select-Object -Property Directory, lastWriteTime |
ForEach-Object -Begin {
     $holder=@{} 
     $results=@()
} -Process {
    $holder.id= [regex]::match($_.Directory,'(\d{8})')
    $holder.modifiedDate = Get-Date  $_.lastWriteTime -Format 'yyyy/MM/dd' 
    $results+=[pscustomobject]$holder
} -End {
    $results
    }  | 
Sort-Object -Property @{Expression = "id"; Descending = $True;}, @{Expression = "modifiedDate"; Descending = $False} | 
Export-csv C:\Users\REDACTED\Desktop\REDACTED.csv
```

This is my first attempt at writing something in powershell purely using the command prompt (which is to say, not scripting in the ISE as if it were Ruby using ifs and so forth) How could I have done this better and should I have organized the pipeline differently? I tried to avoid using variables like would have in the past and focused purely on piping the data I was interested in from beginning to end.

**EDIT**

Based on the comment I got I made these changes. I wasn't able to get rid of all the pipelines and I haven't been able to test if it's faster or not, but I have a feeling even this version has some garbage that could go.

```
$sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *Magic*
$filteredFiles = @()
ForEach($file in $sourceFiles){
    If($file.LastWriteTime.Year -eq 2018){
        $filteredFiles+=[PSCustomObject]@{
            Agency = [regex]::match($file.Directory,'(\d{8})')
            ModifiedDate = Get-Date  $file.lastWriteTime -Format 'yyyy/MM/dd' 
        }
    }
}
$filteredfiles | Sort-Object -Property @{Expression = "Agency"; Descending = 
$True;}, @{Expression = "ModifiedDate"; Descending = $False} |
Export-csv C:\Users\REDACTED\Desktop\REDACTED.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: i'm curious why you want to do this in such an awkward manner that sacrifices speed for "one liner! ooo!". building and tearing down the pipeline adds to the total processing time when there are many objects - it's worth while to sacrifice speed when you need to reduce RAM use, but otherwise, it is generally not sensible. [*grin*] ///// on the improvement side of things, your date test seems to be checking for "in the year 2018". you can simplify that by using `$_.LastWriteTime.Year -eq 2018`. otherwise, things seem OK.

Comment: another idea ... your `$Holder` hashtable seems unneeded. plus, it seems likely to give you nearly random property order. just create the items in the `[PSCustomObject]` call. ///// yet another - your `$resutls` collection seems unneeded. simply put the `[PSCustomObject]` call on it's own line to send that to the pipeline.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey So, should I have done something more like `$sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *Magic*
$filteredFiles = Where-Object {$sourceFiles.lastWriteTime.Year -eq 2018}` 
and then found a way to get the ordered pairs of directories and dates from the files? I was using the pipeline because I was patterning things after a tutorial I watched, but didn't realize it was the reason everything was so incredibly slow

Comment: i would replace the `-Include` with `-Filter`, then add `-File` to ensure i only got back files, and last would _explicitly_ indicate the path with either `-LiteralPath` or `-Path`. the 1st will handle embedded `[]` chars, the 2nd allows wildcards. ///// next i would remove the `+=` since adding to arrays is SLOW. simply use `$Result = foreach ($Thing in $Collection)` to assign the whole set of objects to the collection all at once. ///// last i would use a `[PSCustomObject]` for object-building instead of building a new object with `Select-Object`. a PSCO structure is usually easier to read.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey make an answer using the latter comment. It should comply with OP's request.

Comment: Just curious.. If you want to _get the earliest submission_, why cut off the time part of the `LastWriteTime` datetime property?

Comment: @JosefZ - i will do so. i will need to write something that is a tad different from his since i have no sample data to work with. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution that uses ...

`-Filter` instead of `-Include`
this is usually faster since the filtering is done by the provider [the filesystem in this case] instead of by the cmdlet.

`[PSCustomObject]` object construction
faster than `Select-Object` for building custom objects, since it does not require building/tearing-down a pipeline. plus the `Select-Object` cmdlet has a great deal of complex logic that is not needed here.

`$AgencyList = foreach ($FL_Item in $FileList)` loop assignment
this is VASTLY faster than `$AgencyList +=` for large collections, but only slightly faster for small ones.

```
$SourceDir = $env:TEMP
$Filter = '*itunes*'
$TargetYear = 2019
$ExportFile = "$env:TEMP\jasonmadesomething_AgencyList.csv"

$GCI_Params = @{
    LiteralPath = $SourceDir
    Filter = $Filter
    File = $True
    Recurse = $True
    }
$FileList = Get-ChildItem @GCI_Params |
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime.Year -eq $TargetYear}

$AgencyList = foreach ($FL_Item in $FileList)
    {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        # i don't have any suitable directory info
        #    so i used the BaseName of the file
        Agency = $FL_Item.BaseName.Split('.')[0] -replace '^Itunes_', ''
        LastWriteTime = $FL_Item.LastWriteTime
        }
    }

# this gives a list sorted by ...
#    Agency [alfa sorted 'A' to 'Z' and/or '0' to '9']
#    LastWriteTime [oldest 1st]
$AgencyList = $AgencyList |
    Sort-Object -Property Agency, LastWriteTime

# on screen
$AgencyList

# to CSV
$AgencyList |
    Export-Csv -LiteralPath $ExportFile -NoTypeInformation
```

truncated on screen output ...

```
Agency                  LastWriteTime         
------                  -------------         
AlbumAutoRating_Disable 2019-01-07 12:22:00 PM
AlbumAutoRating_Disable 2019-01-14 12:20:36 PM
AlbumAutoRating_Disable 2019-01-21 12:20:41 PM
AlbumAutoRating_Disable 2019-01-28 12:22:14 PM
AlbumAutoRating_Disable 2019-02-04 12:21:55 PM
[*...snip...*] 
R-PC-SC_Save            2019-01-24 12:38:09 PM
R-PC-SC_Save            2019-02-07 12:37:53 PM
```

truncated CSV file content ...

```
"Agency","LastWriteTime"
"AlbumAutoRating_Disable","2019-01-07 12:22:00 PM"
"AlbumAutoRating_Disable","2019-01-14 12:20:36 PM"
"AlbumAutoRating_Disable","2019-01-21 12:20:41 PM"
"AlbumAutoRating_Disable","2019-01-28 12:22:14 PM"
"AlbumAutoRating_Disable","2019-02-04 12:21:55 PM"
[*...snip...*] 
"R-PC-SC_Save","2019-01-24 12:38:09 PM"
"R-PC-SC_Save","2019-02-07 12:37:53 PM"
```